# Running Dynamic SQL query from groovy

Tags: groovy

I have this query I am trying to run

```
"SELECT * FROM customers where fieldid=2727675;"
```

However fieldid changes all the time. Can I pass the parameter instead and that Parameter has the changing value?

so something like this?
   dynamicvalue = 1234567

"SELECT * FROM customers where fieldid=dynamicvalue;"

Comment: you mean like `params=[foo: 1234567]; sql.rows('select * from customers where fieldid=:foo', params)` ? see [the api doc](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html)

Comment: you can also just use a gstring "SELECT * FROM customers where fieldid=${dynamicValue};"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a custom propertie at your TestCase level, name it fieldid,
then your query should be like :

```
SELECT * FROM customers where fieldid=${#testCase#fieldid};
```

You can fill your parameter dynamically from an excel file using jxl or any other library